# Why is this mapped type losing the type inference of the object literal?

Tags: typescript

This is a contrived, but normally I can pass an object literal to a function and capture the values of the literal in a generic, i.e.:

```js
type Values<V> = {
  a: V;
  b: V;
};

function mapValues<V>(v: Values<V>): V {
  return v as any; // ignore
}
const vn = mapValues({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // inferred number
const vs = mapValues({ a: '1', b: '2' }); // inferred string
```

Both `vn` and `vs` are correctly inferred to `number` or `string` depending on what I passed to `mapValues`.

This even works for indexed types:

```js
function mapValues2<V>(v: { [key: string]: V }): V {
  return v as any;
}
const v2n = mapValues2({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // inferred number
const v2s = mapValues2({ a: '1', b: '2' }); // inferred string
```

The `v` object literal knows it's values are `string`/`number` (respectively), and I'm able to capture that inferred `V` and use it in the return type.

However, once I use a mapped type, i.e.:

```js
enum Foo {
  a,
  b,
}
function mapValues3<K, V>(o: K, v: { [key in keyof K]: V }): V {
  return v as any;
}
const v3n = mapValues3(Foo, { a: 1, b: 2 }); // inferred unknown
const v3s = mapValues3(Foo, { a: '1', b: '2' }); // inferred unknown
```

It is like `V` has forgotten whether it was `string`/`number` (respectively), and I get `unknown` inferred.

Note that if I explicitly type `const v3n: number` then it works, but I want to rely on type inference to figure `V` out for me.

I'm confused why change the `[key: string]` from the 2nd snippet to `[key in keyof K]` in the 3rd would affect the inference of the `: V` side of the object literal's type inference.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer why it fails other than a general intuition that inference of `T` from a function `F<T>` is less reliable the more complex `F` is.  My suggestion here would be to make the inference easier by inferring the type of `v`, like `mapValues3<O, V extends Record<keyof O, unknown>>(o: O, v: V): V[keyof O];`.

Comment: I'd be happy to turn the above into an answer if it matches your use case.

Comment: @jcalz wow, had to work that back to my actual/non-contrived use case, but it worked! Thanks! Yep, if you answer-ize, I'll accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a canonical answer for why this fails.  My intuition is that you are trying to make `mapValue3(o, v)` infer both the keys and values of the `v` argument in a way that's dependent on the keys of the `o` argument, deferring the inference of `V` until it's apparently too late and the compiler gives up with its general `unknown` inference.

Often you have a situation where you have a value `val` of type `U` and are trying to infer a related type `T` from it.  That is, you are thinking of `U` as `F<T>` for some type function `F`, and you want the compiler to infer `T` from `F<T>`.  Assuming such inference is even possible for *anyone* (a lossy function like `type F<T> = T extends object ? true : false` throws away information so you can't infer much about `T` from `F<T>`), it's not always possible for the *compiler*.  If it works, great.

Otherwise, my rule of thumb is this: instead of inferring `T` from a value of type `U`, infer `U` directly.  Then, represent `T` as `G<U>` for some type function `G`.  That is, the `G` type function should be the *inverse* of the `F` function.  (So `G<F<T>>` is `T` for all `T`).  The inverse type function `G` might be more complicated to write than `F`, but if so, a human is probably going to be better at this than the compiler.  Also note that you might need to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) your `U` types to be `F<any>` to make the mapping work.

The above also works for multiple type variables (e.g., values `v1`, `v2`, `v3` of types `U1 = F1<T1, T2, T3>`, `U2 = F2<T1, T2, T3>`, `U3 = F3<T1, T2, T3>` and you want to infer `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` from it: instead, find `G1`, `G2`, and `G3` such that `T1 = G1<U1, U2, U3>`, `T2 = G2<U1, U2, U3>` and `T3 = G3<U1, U2, U3>` and calculate them directly).

So let's do that for your function, rewritten like this:

```
function mapValues3<O, T>(o: O, v: F<O, T>): T {
  return null!
}
type F<O, T> = Record<keyof O, T>; // same as { [key in keyof O]: T };
```

We want to transform it to this:

```
function mapValues3<O, U extends F<O, any>>(o: O, v: U): G<O, U> {
  return null!
}
type G<O, U> = ???;
```

Note that since the first parameter is already just "infer the value of this parameter", there's nothing we need to do for `O`.  The question is: what's `G`?  Given a value of type `U` equal to `Record<keyof O, T>`, how do we get `T` out?  The answer is to use a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
type G<O, U> = U[keyof O];
```

Let's just make sure: `G<O, Record<keyof O, T>` is `Record<keyof O, T>[keyof O]`, which is `{[K in keyof O]: T}[keyof O]`, which evaluates to `T`.  We can eliminate `F` and `G` now and give you this:

```
function mapValues3<O, U extends Record<keyof O, any>>(o: O, v: U): U[keyof O] {
  return null!
}
```

And let's test it out:

```
const v3n = mapValues3(Foo, { a: 1, b: 2 }); // number
const v3s = mapValues3(Foo, { a: "1", b: "2" }); // string
```

Those work the way you want.  Let's also see some possible edge cases:

```
const constraintViolation = mapValues3(Foo, { a: "hey" }); // error! "b" is missing
```

That looks right, since you want the second parameter to have all the keys from the first parameter.  And this:

```
const excessProp = mapValues3(Foo, { a: 1, b: 2, c: false }); // number, no error
```

This may or may not be fine.  It doesn't violate the constraint; it just has extra properties, which are allowed in TypeScript in general (but [forbidden in some situations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)).  The inference is `number` and not `number | boolean` since the extra properties are not consulted when figuring out the return type.  If it's a problem there are ways to make `mapValues3` reject such things, but they're more complicated and this wasn't part of the question.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBqqA2ICmAzgMwA8A8gDSICqi+AHlPmACaGIBK+EcATq1IBrfAE84wRFUSowogHzyAFHABcU6gDd1NAJQ6A2iPGTyAXUQBvAFCJEffFBB8kYEDhwBCANzWAvtbWLCDIiABicHBWtjKUMQBG-oG8YIRQiJrESAC8KBjYeETEShFw1JYy6gCM1PHqAEyIfrreiAD0bYhuyPH4fNYpaRnEHLloWLgEJCWR5ZWIAERVC7XqC-ULTS3tnWl8MGAA5skIQ4NQfKgHUJjwOKiwCIhj+ZNFM2VW8wsAFmKbzVaHXofD4-E8i3imxgHGQMMIB2O53oDAgREIAAUwehnnkJoVpqU5qhqqtEPVqBB1MBcIR8FsgZ1ur0+NQwFE+mD+kA)

Comment: Thanks again! If you're interested in where I ended up using your hint, it's here: https://github.com/stephenh/ts-enum-mapper/blob/master/src/index.ts#L15

Comment: Also really appreciate your detailed rationale/explanation of the "infer U directly, then map against it". I can't apply that intuitively/adhoc yet, but I sorta get it, and will see how it sinks in. :-)